# Каким образом QPointer умудряется обнулять указатель на уничтоженный объект?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Ранее отчего-то считал, что у себя "на кухне" `QPointer` просто производит коннект к сигналу `QObject::destroyed()` контроллируемого объекта (думал, может содержит внутри себя собственный скрытый `QObject` для этой цели). Однако, глянув в исходники `QPointer`, я не заметил ничего подобного. Как так получается, что указатель обнуляется, к примеру, даже в том случае, если объект сам себя удалит или же его удалит совершенно посторонний процесс? Вот `QSharedPointer` так не может, а у `QPointer` получается.

Comment: Глянув на исходники QPointer, заметил что он использует QWeakPointer, т.ч. вам нужно копать глубже

Comment: Да, похоже. И всё, что мне удалось увидеть, так это преобразование содержащегося в `QPointer` (`QWeakPointer`) указателя при помощи `qobject_cast<T*>()`. Думаю, что именно это является ключевым. А уж каким образом последний умудряется проверить существование объекта по адресу, для меня пока загадка. Странно только то, почему `QSharedPointer` не обладает той же возможностью, что и `QPointer`.

Comment: Посмотрите QWeakPointer, по идеи он должен быть способен определить жив объект или мёртв. А QSharedPointer всегда гарантирует что объект, который в нём живёт жив. А если вы специально удаляете объект в обход QSharedPointer, то это не правильная работы с памятью/объектами.